# c# / c++ member function pointers

Tags: c#, c++, delegates

1. Is it possible to store member functions in C++ the way delegates are used in C#?
2. How do Delegates accomplish the object-instance, memberFuncPtr pairs and calls without knowing anything about the instance class?

(note: this questions arose while I was trying to understand events/delegates in publisher/subscriber code design)

I read that:
C++ requires knowledge of a class type such as ClassType::*FuncPtr
C# delegates allow someDelegate += classInstance.memberFunc

Comment: have you explored the features of `std::function`?

Comment: I have not, but I'm writing down to do so right now ;]

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages with different sets of rules. Drawing parallels between them can prove to be counterproductive.

Comment: Delegates in C# is most likely accomplished with some compiler magic, which is why it is a keyword. `std::function`, the closest thing to delegates in C++, is accomplished as a library, and can be written with user code. I don't think there is much else to say about

Comment: @Ron - I'm really trying to understand both languages and how they work a bit better. I always get curious when there is "magic" under the hood. I'll be checking into the std::function that was mentioned a few times and see where that takes me. Again, thanks for the feedback =)

Answer (score 1):

There is type called `std::function`,but if you are using older version of C++ (older than C++11) you will need to use raw function pointers.Check function pointers in C,they are the same for C++.

Answer (score 0):

Not getting exactly what you are asking.
But you can store member functions in form of function pointers in c++.

```
void yourFunc(int x);
int main()
{
  void (*funcPtr)(int)=&yourFunc;
  (*funcPtr)(10);
}
```

Or

A normal function with an int parameter
// and void return type

```
 void fun(int a)
 {
 printf("Value of a is %d\n", a);
 }

int main()
{
// fun_ptr is a pointer to function fun() 
void (*fun_ptr)(int) = &fun;

/* The above line is equivalent of following two
   void (*fun_ptr)(int);
   fun_ptr = &fun; 
*/

// Invoking fun() using fun_ptr
(*fun_ptr)(10);

return 0;
}
```